# The instance member 'X' can't be accessed in an initializer. - Flutter, VoidCallback Function

Tags: android, ios, flutter

So as you might see I'm trying to use the function **addUser** of my StatefulWidget in my StatelessWidget. The only problem is the following error add **HomeWidget(addUser: addUser),**:
The instance member 'addUser' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Can you help me solving that problem?
Thanks a lot.

My StatefulWidget:

```
class _HomeStatefulState extends State<HomeStateful> {

  void addUser() {
   //do something
  }

  final List<Widget> _children = [
    HomeWidget(addUser: addUser),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: _children[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          onTap: onTabTapped,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              title: Text("Home"),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

The StatelessWidget:

```
class HomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeWidget({Key key, @required this.addUser}) : super(key: key);
  final VoidCallback addUser;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SafeArea(
              child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: addUser,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: move your `final List<Widget>  _children = ...` statement inside  `build` function before return statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access `addUser` before the object is initialised. Move the reference in the constructor, e.g.

```
  List<Widget> _children;

  _HomeTestState() {
    _children = [
      HomeWidget(addUser: addUser),
    ];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you're trying to access a function of your Widget before it has been initialised.
If you want to build a "default" setup for your Widget, a good way is to use the initState method.

```
List<Widget> _children;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _children = [
      HomeWidget(addUser: addUser),
    ];
  }
```